# Fastest tree traversal

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I have a pretty large tree data structure that will get updated (nodes removed and added, etc). I have to traverse the tree using breadth first approach to visit all the nodes (to a certain breadth depth like 7) and put it a to a list. Then a function will loop through the nodes and return true if an information was found inside of the list.

This is taking a lot of time to loop through the nodes. I don't think I should map every single node with every single children node and then pull the node using Dictionary and get all its children (recursively). How should I do this? The fastest way is to map all nodes between each other like

`Dictionary<Node, List<Node>>`

- node, list of all children (including children of children...) and then pull the nodes and get its like 2,000 children fast. But if a node is added or removed anywhere, all the dictionary nodes need to be updated (which seems like a hassle). The other way is to dynamically loop through it during run (which takes time). It is a matter of mapping everything together in the beginning during tree generation, or looping during run time.

What is the best way to handle this situation? Any idea, pointers, comments, any thing is helpful. Currently this operation takes about 25% of the program run time.

Comment: Is there any specific ordering to the nodes in your tree?

Comment: Why do you have `Dictionary<Node, List<Node>>` and not node.ChildNodes or something allong those lines?

Comment: AdamS - No there is no ordering in the tree. It is one-to-many relationship all the way down. When I create the tree, do I have to be smart about creating the node like "binary search tree" so that I find the node faster? The problem it seems is when I'm finding node 3-4 children deep, but the middle nodes doesn't give any indication what their children will be. For instance. root node - 23, 1 children - 85 - its children - 3921 - its children - 39222. If I'm trying to find 39222 from root node "23," the middle children is totally different (85, 3921). There it gets tricky it seems?

Comment: Alxandr - that was about mapping all children nodes with its root recursively like a root has 2,000 children but its direct children (one level below) is 4 for instance so Dictionary<root, 2,000 children>

Comment: @iefpw - Can you fill in more details here?  There may be a better way to organize your tree which could lead to improvements over brute force searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just evaluating a predicate you can do that directly while traversing the tree, you don't have to put the full tree into a list first - unless you cache the list. Evaluating the predicate on the the tree nodes directly, you can short circuit / stop traversing early when you first find the information you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a good point. Match it and pull it, instead of adding all nodes. What if I don't know what I want and check all its nodes if they are valid in what I want to do?

Comment: @iefpw: What problem are you trying to solve? Would there maybe be a better / more optimized data structure for your problem?